# return the values in a vector after passing in a function

Tags: r

Basically, I have

`x<-rnorm(5)`.

I write a vector which takes integers  `1 <= n <= 5` then returns in a vector the result from the series `(1/n) * sum_{i=1}^n (1/x_i)`

so

```
 n=1 -> 1   * 1/x_1
 n=2 -> (1/2) * ( 1/(x_1 + x_2) )
 n=3 -> (1/3) * ( 1/(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) )
 n=4 -> (1/4) * ( 1/(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4) )
```

I wrote this function:

```
 series <-  function(n){
       n=seq(1,5,1)
       x<-rnorm(length(n))
       print(x)
  return  (  (1/n)* (1/sum(x[1:length(x[n])]))   )
}
```

But the result is not true, for example

```
 > series(5)
 [1]  1.17810059  0.85472777 -0.55077392 -0.03856963 -0.19404827
 [1] 0.8003608 0.4001804 0.2667869 0.2000902 0.1600722
```

for `n=2 -> 1/2 * 1/x_1 + 1/x_2 = (1/2) * (1/(1.17810059+ 0.85472777))` but unfortunately, the result according to my code is `0.4001804`!

P.S: I want to write the code without loops and without any function needs calling a library! just to define a simple function using the basic known functions in R and then I can save the result, if needed using `Vectorize()` or `outer()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum()` function is not vectorized. It collapsing everything down to a single value. instead, you can use `cumsum()` to get the cumulative some of all the values in the vector thus far.

```
series <-  function(n){
  n <- seq(1,5,1)
  x <- rnorm(length(n))
  print(x)
  return((1/n)* (1/cumsum(x)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the basic idea from @MrFlick, you can also do:

```
1/seq_along(x) * 1/cumsum(x)

[1] -1.7841988 -0.6323886  0.4339966  0.2981289  0.2066433
```

Comment: You don't need `mapply` here. Just `1/seq_along(x) * 1/cumsum(x)` will do

Comment: @MrFlick you are completely right, thank you for noting it :)